# Python EOFerror in online "Zybooks" coding

Tags: python

```
user_num = int(input('Enter integer:\n'))
print(user_num)
print(user_num, 'squared is', user_num * user_num)
print('And', user_num, 'cubed is', user_num * user_num * user_num, '!!')
user_num2 = int(input('Enter another integer:\n'))
print(user_num2)
print(user_num, '+', user_num2, 'is', user_num + user_num2)
print(user_num, '*', user_num2, 'is', user_num * user_num2)
```

My goal is to receive 2 inputs from the viewer, square and cube the first input, receive the second input when prompted then add and multiply the 2 inputs. I get an `EOFerror` for line 5 that says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
    user_num2 = input('Enter another integer:\n')
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

However, if I run the same code in VS it works totally fine. I'm using Zybooks integrated coding area on their website for my class... anyone know what the cause / solution of this problem is?

See [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M07Re.png)

This is the entire assignment page:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5e6EQ.png

Comment: What input do you provide to it? Do you know how exactly Zybooks delivers the input? BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: @wjandrea Zybooks allows for me to add only one input but specifically requests 2 in the instructions. It reads "Enter program input", in which I entered the # 4, like they used in the example. But it has no spot for a second input....

Comment: looks like the problem is Zybooks, not python. Not sure if many people know how working Zybooks's logic...

Comment: @Thionine I agree with rzlvmp, this is more of a question about Zybooks than Python. Looking at the screenshots, it's not clear how you're supposed to provide a second input. Unless you can press Enter inside the "Enter program input" box? If that doesn't work, ask your prof.

Comment: @rzlvmp I thought so too because I couldn't enter another input for the 2nd integer... I've been trying to figure it out for so long and was so frustrated when it worked in VS but not the site. Thanks for the positive affirmation lol

Comment: @wjandrea I think it has to do with the nature of the 2nd input as well... seeing as the code works up until then, thanks for the help and agreement with rzlvmp's hypothesis, I cant do anything other than enter one integer the first time and will ask my prof. or Zybooks support... what a frustrating thing to happen for my first code longer than print("Hello world!")

Comment: @Thionine Woof, getting stuck on the second program... Best of luck to you :)

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out! I was stuck on this one for a bit, you have to add a new line for multiple vars. Hope this helped!

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.