# High/Low game in Python (Guess the Correct Number)

Tags: python

Working on an assignment in ZyBook and keep getting the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/runner/local/submission/HigherLowerGame.py", line 13, in 
upper = int(input("What is the upper bound? "))
EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Including my code but I can not figure out what I am doing wrong, can someone please help me?!

**Here are the instructions for the assignment: **

As a part of this lab, you will need to generate a random number. To do this, you have been given starter code that “seeds” the random number generator. Seeding the generator will help you to know the order in which random numbers will be generated. At the top of the program, you have been given the following lines, which “seed” the random number generator.

Do not change these lines:

```
import random
seedVal = int(input(“What seed should be used? ”)
random.seed(seedVal)
```

Begin developing your code using the develop mode in zyLabs. For the first iteration, write a program that does the following:

Prompts the user to input the lower bound and upper bound. You must use the variables lower for the lower bound, and upper for the upper bound. Include error checks to ensure that the lower bound is less than the upper bound. You must include these exact prompts:
To ask for the lower bound, prompt “What is the lower bound?”
To ask for the upper bound, prompt “What is the upper bound?”
Includes the following line of code to generate a random number between the lower and upper bounds:
random.randint(lower, upper)
Prints the generated number. Use this statement to test your program with different input values by checking to make sure that the generated number is between the upper and lower bounds. Note that this will not be in the final version of the game, but for testing we need to know the number that was generated.
For the second iteration, remove the print statement that displays the generated number, then modify the code so that it does the following:

Prompts the user to guess a number using the exact phrase “What is your guess?”. Include error checks to ensure that the user only enters values between the lower and upper bound.
Prints an output statement based on the guessed number. You must include these exact prompts:
If the number guessed is lower than the random number, print out, “Nope, too low.”
If the number guessed is higher than the random number, print, “Nope, too high.”
If the number guessed is the same as the random number, print, “You got it!”
For the third and final iteration, modify the code to loop until the user guesses the number.

Using develop mode, run your code with different sample inputs.

Switch to Submit Mode in the zyLab developer, and click Submit for Grading. The autograder will run your code through different test cases. If you did not pass all the test cases, check the feedback for errors, modify your code, then resubmit. Remember, this is an optional lab and is not required. "Submit for Grading" will run your code against test cases to give you an idea of whether or not it is working.

**IMPORTANT: You must include *all* possible input values, in order, when using Develop mode, because you will not be able to input additional numbers when the program is running. For example, let's say you wanted to test the game with the following values:

Seed Value: 3 Lower Bound: 1 Upper Bound: 5

You would need to include the following input in the box:

3
1
5
2
5
4
3
1
This would set the seed value as 3, the lower and upper bounds as 1 and 5. Then the test would guess the following numbers, in order: 2, 5, 4, 3, 1. When the correct number is guessed, the program should end. If you do not include all possible values, you may receive errors.

Here is my code so far

```
import random

seedVal = int(input("What seed should be used? "))
random.seed(seedVal)

# Prompt for lower bound
lower = int(input("What is the lower bound? "))

# Prompt for upper bound with error checking
upper = int(input("What is the upper bound? "))
while upper <= lower:
    print("Upper bound must be greater than lower bound.")
    upper = int(input("What is the upper bound? "))

# Generate random number between lower and upper bounds
target = random.randint(lower, upper)

# Loop until the user guesses the number
while True:
    guess = int(input("What is your guess? "))
    
    # Check if guess is lower, higher, or equal to target
    if guess < target:
        print("Nope, too low.")
    elif guess > target:
        print("Nope, too high.")
    else:
        print("You got it!")
        break
```

Comment: I think you missed the instruction "Using develop mode, run your code with different sample inputs".  This sounds like there is somewhere in the interface where you are supposed to prefill the inputs.

Comment: Code that runs on a cloud website generally will not have access to your real keyboard, so you have to supply the input some other way.

Comment: I did prefill the inputs

Comment: 3 1 5 2 5 4 3 1

Comment: Just as it instructed

Comment: Hmm, maybe you entered them in the wrong format?  Does the box allow you to enter them only on a single line, or is it a large text field where you can enter one number on each separate line?

Comment: They are entered on single lines

Comment: Separate lines for each input

Comment: Okay, you said both "single lines" and "separate lines".  Which is it?

Comment: Did you enter `3 1 5 2 5 4 3 1` as one line or as eight lines?

Comment: Sorry I meant each number is on its own separate line

Comment: Well, maybe they expected you to do it the other way?  All as one line?

Comment: I used 8 lines.

Comment: Ok I can try that

Comment: Thank you, I am brand new to coding and this is a lot, I appreciate your help

Comment: It still gives me the error

Comment: I assume there is some mistake in the submission/grading procedure.  Unfortunately I am not familiar with the zybooks product, so I can't really help more, other than to suggest reading over the instructions again and seeing if maybe you missed a step.

Comment: It's odd that the error happens on the upper bound input, which means the first two inputs worked.

Comment: 2511512345 This is the input that it is giving me the error on. Does this make a difference?

Comment: It also works on the 4th input just not the 3rd

Comment: Is that all one number, or are there spaces in between?

Comment: I don't see how it can work on the 4th input if the 3rd input crashes the program.  Once the program crashes, it obviously stops altogether, so it would never get to the 4th...

Comment: Sorry, they would be all individual lines again

Comment: Oh sorry again, ZyBooks gives 4 sample inputs to run the program. And the first two work and the 4th but not the 3rd

Comment: The input `2511512345` is bad.  In the first three numbers, 2 is the seed, 5 is the lower bound, and 1 is the upper bound.  But 1 is lower than 5, so it's going to keep asking for a new upper bound until you enter something bigger than 5.  But that input does not have any numbers bigger than 5, so it eventually runs out of input...

Comment: Oh! You are right! So what would I do to make sure that the program can respond to this error?

Comment: It would be in this part of the code correct?

Comment: # Prompt for upper bound with error checking
upper = int(input("What is the upper bound? "))
while upper <= lower:
    print("Upper bound must be greater than lower bound.\n")
    upper = int(input("What is the upper bound? "))

Comment: There is no good way for the code to handle this error.  The real error is that the input is bad, because it provides a wrong value for the upper/lower bounds and then never provides a correct value.  Where did you get that specific input?  Did you make it up yourself, or was it provided in the course materials?

Comment: No when I submit my code for grading that is the input the course material runs it with.

Comment: This is the expected outcome
What seed should be used? What is the lower bound? What is the upper bound? Lower bound must be less than upper bound.
What is the lower bound? What is the upper bound? What is your guess? You got it!

Comment: Did you doublecheck that specific input to make sure you typed it correctly?

Comment: That expected output does not match the code.  After asking for the lower and upper bound once and getting a wrong answer, it asks for the lower bound again,  which does not match the given code.  The code will only ask for the upper bound again, not the lower bound.

Comment: I dont input it when submitting for grading, the course material does

Comment: So I need to fix it to ask again?

Comment: Yes, if the lower/upper bounds are wrong, you need to ask for them both again.  Not just the upper.

Comment: I got it finally!! Thank you again!

Comment: I'm glad we figured it out.

Comment: Me too! I was stumped and would have been here all day without your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me, running in VSCode. How are you executing the file?

According to some other [similar questions](https://discuss.codecademy.com/t/why-does-this-input-function-return-an-eof-error/585398), it seems this can happen when the script is run in a context where it doesn't have a way to read user input. Try running it in a different editor or through the terminal itself so you can input.

Edit: I'm not familiar with ZyBook, but it seems to be a [fairly common issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68915562/python-eoferror-in-online-zybooks-coding). There wasn't much of a fix found apart from 'add a new line for multiple vars', so perhaps the ZyBook terminal doesn't automatically enter newlines.

Comment: I am submitting in ZyBooks for an assigment

Comment: Perhaps try printing some newlines between your input requests, like `print("\n")`

Comment: Ok, I will try that, thank you for the example. I am new to this so its a little confusing at times

Comment: Still gives me the error

Comment: If it's only breaking on that specific input, it may be due to how Zybook is handling the print before it. Did you try adding the "\n" to the line `print("Upper bound must be greater than lower bound.")`, like `print("Upper bound must be greater than lower bound.\n")`?

Comment: Yes I did exactly as you just showed